# Trying to get click on an openlayers map feature to execute click anchor tag to scroll to bookmark

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, geojson, getelementbyid

I have an openlayers map with a GeoJSON layer of point-features. I would like to get a field in the attribute table (called 'Placeimage') to be passed to a link when the map feature is clicked so the web page scrolls to the correct place.

GeoJSON field name is Placeimage  (a spare field I haven't used)

**HTML**

```
<span id='attribute_value_in_placeimage' href="#place_in_HTML"></span>
```

**JavaScript-Code:**

```
let clickedFeatureIMGName = feature.get('Placeimage');
document.getElementById(clickedFeatureIMGName).click();
```

I've also tried

```
document.getElementById(feature.get('Placeimage')).click();
```

Thanks for the help so far but I'm still getting something wrong.

Comment: You missed a bracket, it should be: document.getElementById(feature.get('Placeimage')).click();

Comment: `document.getElementById(feature.get('Placeimage')).click()` should wok if your links are set up correctly  This example is similar but uses feature id instead of a Placeimage property, click on the Brazil or Canada on the map and the links for those countries will open https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-layer-8zc4o